# Add an article in the tour

Tags: bug, status-completed

The tour says:

> **Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for people interested in conceptual questions about life and challenges in a world where "cognitive" functions can be mimicked in purely digital environment.

However, it *should* say:

> **Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for people interested in conceptual questions about life and challenges in a world where "cognitive" functions can be mimicked in a purely digital environment.

Adding the word 'a' before *purely digital environment.*

Comment: @kenorb It's not necessary. I already mentioned it after the quote, and since part of it is actually in bold, it's confusing.

Comment: I was actually reading from the top and scanning the differences between two quotes until I realized it was written below:) That's why I did it bolded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we quickly describe our site?](http://meta.ai.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/how-can-we-quickly-describe-our-site)

Comment: @kenorb Again, this is different...

Comment: The other is logical follow up, since this would be deprecated once we'll have proper description of our site. Doesn't make sense fix something minor, if we'll change the whole site description. Secondly it says it's completed, so we can close if favor of another to redirect the users to the next thing which is happening related to the tour page.