# The 'A' was added in the tour, but not in the site description!

Tags: bug

In [this question](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1201/add-an-article-in-the-tour), I asked for an 'A' to be added in the tour, in the site description. It was added. But in the dropdown list of sites, it's still gone!

[image: noa]

That should be "...in **a** purely digital...".

Comment: On which page is it?

Comment: Btw. This will be replaced by [new description](http://meta.ai.stackexchange.com/q/1197/8) anyway.

Comment: It's not missing an a it's missing an **s**. *purely digital environment**s***.

Comment: I would suggest removing the 'digital' part since analog devices are also making a fray in AI, as proposed by a question https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/7328/if-digital-values-are-mere-estimates-why-not-return-to-analog-for-ai